# Javascript: window.getComputedStyle(elem, [pseudoClass]) for <input type="text"></input> not returning what it actually shows

Tags: javascript, css

I like to copy the the user agent's style sheet for a text box to create my own HTML composite control. However, that for I use window.getComputedStyle for a simple input-type-text element to retrieve the user agent style.

But it turns out, that the css you get by getComputedStyle is not what the browser visually presents for an input-type-text element.

For example:

- The shown input-type-text has rounded border, but the style does not include that hint.
- The shown input-type-text when not focused has a quite thin border, while the style comes with a ugly thick wanna-be 3D border

I've tried with different browsers. They seem to suffer all the same way - the result looks a little bit differnt each, but as a conclusion, the computed style does not match the visual presentation ...

[image]

That's my code:

TS+JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function build(name: string, pseudoCls: string = undefined): string {
        var x = window.getComputedStyle($("#t1")[0], pseudoCls);
        var z = window.getComputedStyle($("#d1")[0], pseudoCls);

        var newStyle = "." + name;
        if (pseudoCls) {
            newStyle += ":" + pseudoCls;
        }
        newStyle += "{\n";
       let alreadyExistingProps : { [key: string]: string } = {};
       for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            let prop = z.item(i);
            let propValue = z.getPropertyValue(prop);
            if (typeof propValue === "string" && propValue) {
                alreadyExistingProps[prop] = propValue;
            }
        }
      
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            let prop = x.item(i);
            let propValue = x.getPropertyValue(prop);
            if (typeof propValue === "string" && propValue) {
                if (!alreadyExistingProps.hasOwnProperty(prop)
                   || alreadyExistingProps[prop] !== propValue)
                  {
                    newStyle += prop + ": " + propValue + ";\n";
                    console.log(prop + ":" + propValue);
                  }
            }
        }
        console.log("a");
        newStyle += "\n}";
        return newStyle;
    }

    var sheet = document.createElement("style");

    sheet.innerHTML = build("txtBoxLikeStyle", "focus");
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);

    sheet = document.createElement("style");
    sheet.innerHTML = build("txtBoxLikeStyle", "active");
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);

    sheet = document.createElement("style");
    sheet.innerHTML = build("txtBoxLikeStyle", "hover");
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);

    sheet = document.createElement("style");
    sheet.innerHTML = build("txtBoxLikeStyle");
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="t1" type="text" value="this is an iput element">
<p/>
<div id="d1" class="txtBoxLikeStyle">this is a div element</div>
<p/>
The div copies the style of the input-text element, but as you can see, it looks pretty differnt ...
```

https://codepen.io/Luegisdorf/pen/oNqmQpN

So the question: What is wrong with my code - or are all browser broken somehow?

**EDIT**: Have adjusted the code a little bit, to ommit useless css properties when creating runtime style. The behavior is the same, but it cleans a little bit the analysis part ...

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to see exactly what CSS is being set. I see at a glance that there is a light and dark internal option on the border color for example.

Comment: The shown computed style in Dev-Tools for an input-type-text also misses border roundings and have the same ugly border settings as retrieved by getComputedStyle. This proofs again, that computed style is not what the browser actually displays ...